# how to build an algorithm that is not in terms of M

Tags: math

X and Y agree to meet each other at a certain time. X shows up at time t (where t can range from 1 to n) with a probability x and Y shows up at time t with a probability y. Time t is in seconds.

I need an algorithm that runs in O(nlogn) time to calculate the probability that Y shows up after X.

The probabilities of X and Y are independent of each other

I tried to calculate an expression for the probability that X shows up M seconds before Y and plugging in all the t values (from 1 to n) and calculating the sum of all probabilities. But I will only get the probability in terms of M.

Comment: Do you have the assumption that X and Y's times of arrival are independent?

Comment: @Stef yes the probabilities of X and Y are independent

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to programming? Isn't this a pure math problem?

Comment: The O(n log(n)) requirement is a bit odd. There is a simple solution in O(n), and of course O(n) ⊂ O(n log(n)), but I'd be hard-pressed to come up with a solution that really makes a logarithm appear. Typically, log(n) appears in algorithm complexity if the algorithm sorts a list of size n, or performs some kind of binary search, or uses a structure like a balanced binary tree. None of that is relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

The pobability of X showing up after Y is the sum of P(y>i)p(x=i). The basic approach in O(n²) is for each i, for each j > i sum x(i)y(j), but there is a more efficient way to calculate this :
P(y > i ) = 1 - P(y <= i) so at each step you store the last p(y <= i) and you can even achieve O(n)

it would look like:

```
ysmaller = 0
total = 0
for i in range(n):
  ysmaller += y[i]
  total += x[i] * (1 - ysmaller)
```

Comment: Note that you could also iterate in reverse, to get P(y > i) directly rather than P(y <= i). Or you could iterate like you do, but compute P(y <= x) instead of P(y > x); then at the end, return 1 - total.

Comment: @Stef Or view it from the other person's side, accumulate x instead.

Comment: @KellyBundy Right! `sum_i P(y > i) P(x=i) == sum_i P(y = i) P(x < i)`

Comment: @Stef Or as Python: `sum(map(mul, accumulate(x), y[1:]))` ([test](https://tio.run/##XZDdasMwDIXv9RS6tLeWJexmFPokJQyvdTaD/5AVSJ4@k52lhPlGPug7R0J54Z8U3z8yretIKSCZ@JDiQk7Efwpax7ElTsmXvWnu9ylM3rDdgJQtGU6096UH8LAjZkpfRUV9AZRHeMXbFqw0jsJ/oot11LcVaGhQEahMQZHePJYnimJ7K81BzTEAROH6roNZ6j4GlqOApQTjva1jO@DExrdfjXHHwXW7J/t6xeXm6i6bQ/QsGl9Q9Xh@chKfyUVWjRK159fdg8lKbnA6HErN@iTB/WXQ/6zr@gs))